# How to print message on JSP page after a certain time

Tags: jsp, time, timer, timeout

I have a complex Requirement.Let  me put it very simple.

There is a JSP page, which has a button NEXT.If the user clicks next within 5 minutes then he is taken to the NEXT page, but suppose user does nothing and sits idles then automatically after 5 mins message should be printed on the screen "Timeout".

How would I accomplish this.How would I keep the track of time.
Request you to help me with a code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) function to execute a function after a certain amount of time has passed:

```
window.setTimeout(showMessage, 5*60*1000);
```

Comment: ok. now that u have understood my questiuon i`ll reveal some of my complexities.When the JSP page loads, I extract the Session ID fr4om the URL.Session ID timeout after 10 mins of inactivity.If user clicks NEXT after 10 mins,then along with data expired Session id will also be passed.What I want to do is to fire a dummy query so that my session id keeps alive every say 9 mins. I am now much into Java so i am unaware of big concepts like jquery, AJAX. KINDLY HELP!!!!

Comment: @Sankalp, that sounds like your other question I already answered.  You can learn more about AJAX and jQuery with these tutorials: http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/ajax_callbacks_with_jquery.html http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/  They should be enough to get you through this problem.  I would recommend learning a lot more though.